# PHP Magento Mage_Core_Exception Invalid login or password

Tags: php, magento, authentication, magento-1.4, fatal-error

I am running a Magento Store and have created a seperate login outside of the root folder.  I moved the store from Bluehost to Rackspace cloud and now I get this message when trying to login

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid login or password.' in myDomain/store/app/Mage.php:536 Stack trace: #0 myDomain/store/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(121): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid login o...', 2) #1 myDomain/store/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(182): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->authenticate('user@myDomain....', 'password') #2 myDomain/dashboard/setup_mage.php(16): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->login('user@myDomain....', 'password') #3 myDomain/dashboard/all_includes.php(7): require_once('/home/myDomain/p...') #4 myDomain/dashboard/dashboard.php(4): require_once('/home/myDomain/p...') #5 {main} thrown in myDomain/store/app/Mage.php on line 536

Extra info

Works fine on original bluehost site.

Upon moving the site to rackspace I emptied all cache and session in var/cache and var/session and also changed all URLs in core_config_data table to the new domain.

Site works find, but just trying to login it kicks out this Fatal error.

Mylogin Code:

```
          umask(0);
          Mage::app("default");
          Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));
          $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
          $email=$_POST['miniLogin']['username'];
          $password=$_POST['miniLogin']['password'];

          $session->login($email, $password);
```

Fatal error message at $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you move the database over? More than likely the encoding was incorrect and has invalidated the MD5 checksum for passwords, etc.

Comment: Boomer, I exported the original database with PHPMYADMIN and then imported the file with Virtualmin.  This set up all tables and inported the original data... I of course changed the core_config_data table to represent the new domain name and I deleted all the old Cache files.  The store works great, shows products and everything.. cart etc.  But no login?

Comment: One more thing Boomer... If I use the IP address instead of the domain I can login fine???

Comment: ensure your cookie domain is set properly in the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the login in a try block and the problem was solved.

```
try{ 
    $session->login($email, $password);
   }
catch(Exception $e) {}
```